# apt is stuck when installing new applications

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

When I am trying to install a new package using `apt` or `apt-get` I get this error message:

```
$ sudo apt install sl
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So, I am following the instructions:

```
$ dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up icaclient (13.10.0.20) ...
```

It is taking forever so after some time I press ctrl+c, and it results in this:

```
^Cdpkg: error processing package icaclient (--configure):
installed icaclient package post-installation script subprocess was interrupted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icaclient
```

So now when I try again to install a package, it looks like it works:

```
$ sudo apt install sl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
sl is already the newest version (3.03-17build2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm7 linux-headers-4.15.0-50 linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-50-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 398 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

And after pressing Y:

```
Setting up icaclient (13.10.0.20) ...

Progress: [  0%] 
[...................................................]
```

Now it is stuck again and I can not ctrl+c out of it. When I close the terminal screen, it repeats from the beginning of the post.

How can I solve this?

n.b. I use the icaclient application on a daily basis, but I can probably install it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was hanging on the post-installation script as it stated in one of the error messages above. After some searching I found that you can the post-installation scripts are stored at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`

So I could fix it easily using:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/icaclient.postinst
```

After that i had to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and remove some lock files.

Now apt is working as it should!